# Error while using samba for file sharing - convert name "Everyone" to a SID

Tags: samba

I get the following error when using samba for file sharing:

```
Net usershare returned error 255: net usershare add: 
cannot convert name "Everyone" to a SID.
The transport connection attempt was refused by the remote system.
```

Perhaps smbd is not running? 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFtqN.jpg)

Comment: I am having the same issue. To help get a response, please identify your operating system and which version of Samba you are using. I am using Ubuntu 16.04. This problem appeared when I upgraded to Samba version 4.7.12

Comment: I restored Samba Version 4.3.11-Ubuntu. After researching and testing I have come to believe that Samba Version 4.7.12 may be incompatible with Ubuntu 16.04. Restoring Samba Version 4.3.11-Ubuntu **resolved** the issues identified in this question.

Answer (score 1):

You will in fact get that error if smbd is not running so ... um ... start it:

```
sudo service smbd start
```

Comment: Received same error message as poster. When you run `sudo service smbd start` you get the error message: `Failed to start smbd.service: Unit smbd.service not found.` Have reloaded Samba several of times.